# Chaining function using 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
    Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
    Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
    void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Test obj1;
    obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
    obj1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, if I use the chaining functions, values of x and y it comes to be : x=10, y=0 instead of x=10 , y=20

If instead of chaining function, I use:
obj1.setX(10) and obj1.setY(20) separately, 
x value comes to be 10
y value comes to 20. 
Can someone please explain why it is like this.

Comment: Prints 10/20 for me... are you sure you weren't e.g. running the wrong executable after modifying the code?

Comment: Your code looks good to me. It works for me too, using g++ 4.8.4.

Comment: Do you have a method which sets values, which you haven't added here? Whatever you have put up works.

Comment: Works as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9a699eabeebe278). Are you sure you don't forget reference in your return type of your setter in your code ?

Comment: Sorry, i put the question wrongly... just edited it.... instead of the following:
Test& setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
it is this Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }

Answer (score 1):

Your set* methods are returning copies of the Test object.

So when you chain your calls, the setY is applied to the temporary copy, and thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

You can either return a reference on an object:

```
Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
Test &setY(int b) { x = b; return *this; }
```

Or to store copy of changed object:

```
Test obj1;
Test objCopy = obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
objCopy.print();
```

First is more efficient due to not copying object.